# Как разместить две картинки друг от друга?

Tags: html, css

Не могу разместить картинки друг от друга как на фото [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока вышло только так:
HTML

```
<div id="header" >
    <div id="inner_wrap_logo">
        <img src="img/sm.png" style="width: 178px; height: 280.6px; ">
        <img src="img/cross.png" style="width: 194px; height: 214px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 501px;
background: url(../img/header2.jpg);
}

#inner_wrap_logo{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
height: 100%;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 501px;
  background: url(http://conceptartworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Tank_Concept_Art_by_Chad_Weatherford_01.jpg);
}
#inner_wrap_logo {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="inner_wrap_logo">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/CoA_of_Russian_Empire_(1730).png" style="width: 194px; height: 214px;">
    <img src="http://abali.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/korolevskiy_Royal_CoA_of_Norway.png" style="width: 194px; height: 214px;float:right;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `#inner_wrap_logo` нужно задавать `overflow: hidden;` или `clearfix`

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko зачем?

Comment: Затем, что внутри плавающий блок второе изображение `img {float: right; }`

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1 flex:**

```
#header{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 501px;
background: url(../img/header2.jpg);
}

#inner_wrap_logo{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
height: 100%;  

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

**Вариант 2 float:**

```
#header{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 501px;
background: url(../img/header2.jpg);
}

#inner_wrap_logo{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
height: 100%;  

overflow: hidden;
}

#inner_wrap_logo img:first-of-type{
  float:left;
}

#inner_wrap_logo img:last-of-type{
  float:right;
}
```

...

Answer (score 1):

## Html

```
<div id='one'>
  Text 1
</div>

<div id='two'>
  Текст 2
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#one, #two
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```